# Infinite movie animation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, infinite-loop

From my previous question, I have tried to understand how to create frames or to play an animation in Matlab. I have clarified everything, but now I'm trying to figure out how to play it infinitely. For example let us consider two snippets of code. The first from  my previous question

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
FRAMES = 32;                  %// Total number of frames
for k = 1:FRAMES
    ph = k * 2 * pi / FRAMES; %// Accumulate phase
    plot(x, sin(x + ph))      %// Generate plot
    grid, axis equal
    M(k) = getframe;          %// Capture frame
end

%// Play movie 10 times
movie(M, 10)
```

This plays the movie 10 times. But let us consider a second case of what I am trying to do

```
for k = 1:16
    plot(fft(eye(k+16)))
    axis equal
    M(k) = getframe;
end
while 1
movie(M,10)
end
```

It starts an animation and after a few seconds it stops. I have put `movei(M,10)` into

```
while 1

end
```

because I wanted to play it infinitely or create an infinite loop. But it does not do its job properly. So please advice me. Is it possible for Matlab to create infinite movies?

Comment: you can just make movie(M,inf) ?

Comment: i will try  right now

Comment: i found  also that instead of 16 in loop,use  inf

Comment: so if you would like post as  answer,i will accept it

Comment: I don't think that using `Inf` would work here.

Comment: yes not only  inf in movie,but inf in loop as well,both together  should work.i have checked it

Comment: @dato If that works for you, then please make sure that the accepted answer reflects that.

Comment: it contains one part  just,but btw  i have accepted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just make movie(M,inf)

Comment: This would make sense but they must have gotten rid of that feature. For me, MATLAB R2015b Linux complains that repetition count must be finite.